# Custom Performance Counters in Azure - Not being persisted to WADPerformanceCountersTable

Tags: azure

I've followed this Tutorial exactly, http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/performance-profiling/ and although I can see my Custom Performance Counters in perfmon, they are never persisted to the WADPerformanceCountersTable.

Anyone else experienced this problem?

It's probably worth saying the the System Performance Counters are working just fine - they persist as expected.

Comment: I think there is the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062475/custom-performance-counters-are-not-logged

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that yesterday and followed the code in the question. Again, I can see the Counter in Perfmon, but it's not persisted in the WADPerformanceTable.